# How do I create a custom ADFS 2nd factor sign in page?

Tags: authentication, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs, development, google-authenticator

I have a C# dll that provides HOTP and TOTP authentication.  I'd like to adapt this for use with ADFS sign in pages.  (I'll share this DLL with you if you like)

How do I integrate my authentication DLL into ADFS?

[I see on this page that it's possible](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280950.aspx) to create such a thing, and Microsoft PhoneFactor is already doing it.

What is missing is how do I integrate an arbitrary DLL into this process.  I'm sure that I need to link to specific URLs, hook to specific interfaces, but I can't find the documentation for this.

**Quote**

> You can also use external authentication providers. This approach can enable AD FSto integrate with additional services, such as Windows Azure Active Authentication, or you can develop your own provider.

The linked documentation takes me to authorization rules, which I'm not very familiar with, but regardless, I don't think that is the technical depth I need to integrate my solution.

So how do I integrate PhoneFactor or a 3rd party DLL into ADFS?

Answer (score 2):

Even better...
http://blogs.technet.com/b/cloudpfe/archive/2014/10/26/using-time-based-one-time-passwords-for-multi-factor-authentication-in-ad-fs-3-0.aspx

This lists the entire TOTP solution for AD FS.

Comment: Though the answer may be correct, we prefer to see answers, which not only linking to some external site, but also describe the solution to the question here. See also [How to answer](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I presume from the link you provided that you are referring to ADFS on Server 2012 R2?

Have a look at:

[How to create a Custom Authentication Provider for Active Directory Federation Services on Windows Server 2012 R2 - Part 1](https://blogs.technet.com/b/cloudpfe/archive/2014/02/01/how-to-create-a-custom-authentication-provider-for-active-directory-federation-services-3-0-part-1.aspx).